# BlueJ: My code compiles with no errors but the program won't run

Tags: java, syntax, bluej

For my computing gcse, i have to write code which takes a text file, i used JFK's moon speech and pasted it into a word file five times, and the code has to do a few things; -Rewrite the speech with no duplicates -Rewrite the speech but in digits. each word in the speech (excluding duplicates) are given a number which corresponds with the position of the word in the speech When compiling the code im getting no syntax errors but when i run the program the program displays: "Error Occurred Error occured when writing file" i have no clue on how to fix this so if anyone could take a look at my code and suggest how to fix it that'd be a great help.
http://pastebin.com/3avu4ni3

Comment: Code should be included **in the question itself**. If it's too large, condense it into a [mcve]. Also: in your `catch` blocks, be sure to include a `ex.printStackTrace()`, so that you'll see the exact, actual error. And be sure to include that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually your error was very simple.

1. Your code does not handle the Exception where there is no data written in the ImportantSentence.txt
   If you write anything inside it, save it and then run your code you will see it works just fine.
2. I think you put the file in the incorrect path and it was not finding it. Since you did not add a case that checks the existence of the txt and creates it if it does not finds it, then the error occurred. I have done the above two checks and everything works just fine.

[image: Location of txt files, in this case]

Hope it helps.
Best regards